# Button Aligned with Dropdownlist missing border in column

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have two dropdownlists with buttons aligned next to each in columns.  I'm having a weird problem with the display of the dropdownlist/button combination in the first column.

[image]

The button "loses" its right border in the first column.  I thought perhaps there was something different between the two so I switched the one on right (which displays correctly) with the one on the left.  After the switch, it was now missing the right border, so the issue seems to be with the column, but the columns are the same.  Here is the HTML for both dropdownlists:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" EnableOutsideScripts="true" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" BackColor="White">
<div class="form-group" runat="server" id="EmployeePicker" visible="true" style="background-color:white !important">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon input-group-btn" style="background-color:white !important;border:none">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployee" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <span class="tool-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Configure employee permissions."><button id="btnEmployeeConfig" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" onclick="javascript:OpenModal('copyEmployeeModal')"><i class="s7-config" style="font-size:x-large;"></i></button>
                        </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group" style="background-color:white !important;border:none">
                <span class="input-group-addon input-group-btn" style="background-color:white !important;border:none">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployeeSiteGroup" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="false" Enabled="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <span class="tool-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Configure group permissions."><button id="btnEmployeeGroupConfig" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" onclick="javascript:OpenModal('copyEmployeeGroupModal')"><i class="s7-config" style="font-size:x-large"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" runat="server" id="SiteGroupPicker" visible="false">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon input-group-btn"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSiteGroup" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSiteGroup_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList><button class="btn btn-default" id="btnGroupConfig" runat="server" onclick="javascript:OpenModal('configGroupModal')"><i class="s7-config" style="font-size:x-large"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please add full code snippet to find out border issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border:none` from line

```
<span class="input-group-addon input-group-btn" style="background-color:white !important;border:none">
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, that put a line almost through the button.

Comment: border:none there removes the border for the entire input-group, not the button.  If you look at the code sample both input groups have that.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff, please add full code snippet to find out border issue.

Comment: Please add execute-able code snippet like jsfiddle, I will check your code by click button "Run code snippet". I hope, you get my point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160228/discussion-between-billu-g-and-rani-radcliff).

Comment: I have no idea how to add asp.net webform controls to jsfiddle, I'm not even sure that it is possible, but thank you for trying to help.